# Downgrade from 14.04 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, downgrade

I recently installed version 14.04 on ubuntu laptop and sadly regretted it. Is it possible to downgrade back to 12.04 and if so, how?

Thanks

Comment: Do a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 or install xubuntu-desktop package in Ubuntu 14.04. You can also install kde-plasma-desktop package. This way you'll be able to boot into XFCE session (nice one) and also into KDE plasma desktop session which is also fast and you can completely forget all the troubles you experienced with unity.

Answer (score 2):

@parto links something usefull

What I want to point out is that **if you have different partitions for /(root) and home**
you can **boot with live cd (12.04)** choose something different in the options to **manually decide your partitioning** .

**Mount everything as before** home to home, swap to swap and root to root ( / ) **but you have to format this system partition ( with the ubuntu version you choose )**

With this you **still have to get all the apps and packages** you need but **some of your customization** will still stand because for example **firefox and thunderbird (.) hidden folder exists in your home directory** .

**If you don't have partitions** and you decided to make one big piece for everything you must already have a copy of your essential files , in that case **make a new installation with partitions to avoid this in the future** .

Don't forget to **back up of your files** , just in case .

There are some very good guides for partitioning take a look if necessary .

I hope it helps